# Any way to have bar graph row show different transition rate in D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

Is there any way to make the transition of each row with different transition rate and provide them with different minimum and maximum value. Currently all the bars are expanding their size simultaneously - want to have different value for initial point and final point.

Thanks

```
<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="jqueryui@1.10.0" data-semver="1.10.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />
  <script data-require="jqueryui@1.10.0" data-semver="1.10.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="slider"></div>
  <script>
    $(function() {

      $("#slider").slider({
        min: 100,
        max: 500,
        // on slide adjust width of all rects
        slide: function(event, ui) {
          svg.selectAll("rect")
            .attr("width", ui.value);
        }
      });

      // create svg
      var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 600)
        .attr("height", 600);

      // add 4 rects
      svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data([1, 2, 3, 4])
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", 10)
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return d * 25;
        })
        .attr("height", 20)
        .attr("width", 100);

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You simply have to set those different start and end points for the attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In d3, you can pretty much control everything as long as you have the information in your data.
You can control the width of the bar base on your data binded to the dom, for example:

```
var data = [ { rate:1.1, max:100 }, { rate:1.2, max:200 }, { row:1.3, max:300 }, { row:1.4, max:400 }];

$("#slider").slider({
    min: 100,
    max: 500,
    // on slide adjust width of all rects
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      svg.selectAll("rect")
        .attr("width", function (d) {
             return Math.max(ui.value * d.rate, d.max);
        });
    }
});
```

This obviously not what you exactly want, but I am just trying to show you can flexibly adjust your ui base on the provided data, which is indeed the core of D3 (data driven UI). Hopefully this help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <link data-require="jqueryui@1.10.0" data-semver="1.10.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />
    <script data-require="jqueryui@1.10.0" data-semver="1.10.0" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src='http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="slider"></div>
<script>
    $(function() {

        $("#slider").slider({
            min: 100,
            max: 500,
            // on slide adjust width of all rects
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                svg.selectAll("rect")
                        .attr("width", function (d) {
                            return Math.min(ui.value * d.rate, d.max);
                        });
            }
        });

        // create svg
        var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", 600)
                .attr("height", 600);

        // add 4 rects
        var data = [
            { row:1, rate:1.1, max:100 },
            { row:2, rate:1.2, max:200 },
            { row:3, rate:1.3, max:300 },
            { row:4, rate:1.4, max:400 },
        ];

        svg.selectAll("rect")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x", 10)
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return d.row * 25;
                })
                .attr("height", 20)
                .attr("width", 100);

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```